# In django, how to use another model data from function based views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

So I have a form that updates a `key_instance` object with a borrower. Currently my app needs the user to enter the name of the borrower, but I want it to display a dropdown list of data from another model the `user` model to select from, is there anyway to do this in a class based view? Here are my `views.py` and my template. What I was thinking is that I would like to use a `get_list_or_404` on the user model and display it as a drop down list in the template and use that selection to populate the form field.

I manged to get the dropdown list to display in my template but I'm not sure as to how to save that value in my views.

Does anyone know if this is the right way or if this is doable? Thank you!!

views.py

```
def submit_key_request(request, pk):

    """
    View function for renewing a specific keyInstance by admin
    """
    key_inst=get_object_or_404(KeyInstance, pk=pk)
    names = get_list_or_404(Users)

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):

        form = UpdateKeyForm(request.POST)


        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required (here we just write it to the model due_back field)
            key_inst.is_requested = True
            key_inst.status = 'r'
            key_inst.date_requested = datetime.date.today()
            key_inst.borrower = form.cleaned_data['borrower']
            key_inst.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-available-keys') )


    # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
    else:

        form = UpdateKeyForm(initial={'borrower': 'N/A'})

    return render(request, 'catalog/keyinstance_request_update.html', {'form': form, 'keyinst':key_inst})
```

template

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="centered"> <h1>Request Keys For Room: {{keyinst.roomkey}}</h1></div>



<div class="square-box">
    <div class="square-content">
    <form action="" method="post" >

        {% csrf_token %}
        <table style="display: inline-flex">
        {{ form}}
        </table>
        <select name = 'name'>
        {% for name in names %}
            <option value="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <p>
            (Please use their login name i.e. <b>{{ user.get_username }}</b>)
        </p>
        <p><input required id="checkBox" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()"> I accept the <a href="{% url 'key-agreement'%}">terms and conditions</a></p>
        <p id="text" style="display:none">You Have Agreed To the Terms and Conditions</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I manged to do it, Not sure if this is the best 'pythonic' or best practice. Please let me know if it's not.

my views.py

```
def submit_key_request(request, pk):

    """
    View function for renewing a specific keyInstance by admin
    """

    key_inst=get_object_or_404(KeyInstance, pk=pk)
    names = get_list_or_404(User)

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']

        key_inst.is_requested = True
        key_inst.status = 'r'
        key_inst.date_requested = datetime.date.today()
        key_inst.borrower = name
        key_inst.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-available-keys') )


    # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
    else:
        pass


    return render(request, 'catalog/keyinstance_request_update.html', {'keyinst':key_inst, 'names':names})

template

{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="centered"> <h1>Request Keys For Room: {{keyinst.roomkey}}</h1></div>



<div class="square-box">
    <div class="square-content">
    <form action="" method="post" >

        {% csrf_token %}
        </br>
        <select name = 'name' required>
        {% for key in names %}
            <option value="{{ key }}">{{ key }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <p>
            (Please use their login name i.e. <b>{{ user.get_username }}</b>)
        </p>
        <p><input required id="checkBox" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()"> I accept the <a href="{% url 'key-agreement'%}">terms and conditions</a></p>
        <p id="text" style="display:none">You Have Agreed To the Terms and Conditions</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```